# Any Static Application Security Testing (SAST) Tools for f#

Tags: f#, static-code-analysis

Looking for open source tool for f#
Have seen a few that support c#:
  https://pumascan.com/
  https://security-code-scan.github.io/

But cant find any for f#.
Just wonder do f# people do ci/cd and have a pipeline stage for static analysis and if so what do they use

Comment: C# and F# compile to the same intermediate language, so you should get some mileage out of any .NET tool that works on that level. Some of the code quality metrics you should take with a grain of salt though, as the compiled code doesn't reflect the F# source code directly.